# ConversionFailedException in Spring Data JPA Integration Test with Page<> Return Type

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing

I'm using Spring Data JPA along with PostgreSQL for my application's persistence layer. In my repository, I've defined a custom JPA query to retrieve orders by merchant and status, and I'm using the Page return type to handle pagination. The query is functional and works as expected when invoked through my API.

To ensure the correctness of this custom query, I'm attempting to write an integration test for it using TestContainers to set up a PostgreSQL container. However, when I run the integration test, it fails with a ConversionFailedException, specifically:

```
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value '40288bea8a1e0f3d018a1e0f4bce0001'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "40288bea8a1e0f3d018a1e0f4bce0001"
```

The exception indicates that Spring is trying to convert the entity's ID from String to Long, even though the ID is of type String. This behavior occurs exclusively in the integration test, while the custom query works without issues when invoked through the API.

**Entity Code:**

```
@Entity
public class Order extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;
    
    //Other fields, getters and setters
}
```

**Jpa Query:**

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM \"ORDER\" as o \n" +
            "WHERE \"ID_MERCHANT\" = ?1 \n" +
            "AND (?2 IS NULL OR \"ID_STATUS\" = (SELECT \"ID\" FROM \"STATUS_ORDER\" WHERE \"STATUS\" = ?2 ))\n" +
            "ORDER BY \"DATE\" DESC", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Order> findAllByMarchanAndStatusByDate(String idMerchant, String statusName, Pageable pageable);
```

**Integration test method:**

```
class OrderRespositoryAdapterTest extends IntegrationTestConfig {
    @Autowired
    private OrderRespository underTest;
    @Autowired
    private StatusOrderRepository statusOrderRepository;
    @Autowired
    private MarchantRepository marchantRepository;
    private EasyRandom easyRandom; // Dependencie that fill dummy objects with dummy values
    private Marchant marchant;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        //Set up StatusOrders
        statusOrderRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(new Status("Processing"), new Status("Completed")
                , new Status("Failed"), new Status("Canceled")));
        //Set up Merchant
        marchant = MarchantRepository.save(new Marchant());
    }

    @Test
    void shoudlReturnOrdersWithStatusCompleted() {
        //given
        List<Order> dummyOrders = easyRandom.objects(Order.class, 1).collect(Collectors.toList());
        //Setting status
        dummyOrders.get(0).setStatus(statusOrderRepository.findByName(STATUS.Completed.name()).get());
        //Setting Merchant
        dummyOrders.get(0).setMarchant(marchant);
        underTest.saveAll(dummyOrders);
        //when
        PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, dummyOrders.size());
        System.err.println(underTest.findAll(pageRequest).getContent());
        Page<Order> result =underTest.findAllByMarchanAndStatusByDate(marchant.getId(), STATUS.Completed.name(), pageRequest); // Failure Occurs in this Line
        //then
        long expected = 0;
        assertThat(result.getContent().size()).isEqualTo(expected);
        assertThat(true).isTrue();
    }
}
```

**NB 1:** IntegrationTestConfig is responsible for orchestrating the setup of the PostgreSQL database instance and modifying the database connection properties to ensure successful connectivity. This aspect of the configuration is functioning as intended.

I experimented with testing the issue using an H2 database, but unfortunately, the problem persisted. To address this, I opted for TestContainers to replicate a production-like database environment for testing purposes which is PostgreSQL.

It's worth noting that an intriguing aspect emerged: when I altered the return type of the custom query to List from Page, the integration test executed without encountering any exceptions.

Surprisingly, the built-in findAll method from Spring Data JPA, when employed with a return type of Page, functioned perfectly without encountering any difficulties.